# Identify which remote repository a file came from

Tags: git

If I am using git and use sparse checkout to pull a single directory from a separate repository is there any way after the fact to tell what repository that file came from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to do a sparse checkout you need to edit the file *.git/info/sparse-checkout* so you should be able to find it there.

Comment: thats true but the .git/info/sparse-checkout might have a bunch of entries or might have changed, is there any way to tie an entry in the sparse-checkout file to a particular sparse checkout?

Comment: Perhaps I'm not reading the question right. The sparse-checkout file contains lists of directories to include or exclude. The file you wish to know something about is located in one of those directories and thats where it came from. If you stop using sparse checkout (ie checkout the complete tree) you will lose all information about which directory it came from. If you use several repositories you will always be able to see wich one you're working in with a simple `git status`